# android-n-preview-3 build for nexus 6p

Tags: android, build

## android@compiler172:~/work/AndroidNPreview3$ make -j32

```html
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=6.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_angler
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv8-a
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a53
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=arm
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=cortex-a7
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-3.5.0-23-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-12.04-precise
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
```

============================================
make: *** No rule to make target `prebuilts/build-tools/linux-x86/bin/ckati', needed by`out/build-aosp_angler.ninja'.  Stop.

make failed to build some targets (1 seconds)

when i build refs/tags/android-n-preview-3 for my nexus 6p but failed.
How can i do with this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the new AOSP build system uses the new *build-tools* project. They've probably just forgot to include this project in the updated manifest for android-n-preview-3.

You have two options:

1) Include the project into your [local_manifest](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/local_manifests-cookbook):

```
<project path="prebuilts/build-tools" name="platform/prebuilts/build-tools" revision="refs/tags/android-n-preview-3" />
```

2) Clone it by yourself:

```
cd ~/work/AndroidNPreview3
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/build-tools prebuilts/build-tools
```